# Does USB power delivery support arbitrary voltages?

Tags: power-supply, power, usb, usb-c

I'm looking for a USB power delivery power adapter to charge my Canon EOS RP camera via its USB-C port. Canon sells its own adapter for insane prices, and the Canon adapter is apparently nothing but a USB power delivery adapter, so according to my logic, a cheaper adapter should work.

One adapter (90 W) I'm looking at says in the specs:

- 5-18 V / 5 A, 19-20 V / 4,5 A

Another adapter (65 W) I'm looking at says in the specs:

- 5 V / 3 A, 9 V / 3 A, 12 V / 3 A, 20 V / 3,25 A

The adapter with only 5V, 9V, 12V and 20V is significantly cheaper.

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_hardware#PD), USB power delivery supports 5V, 9V, 12V, 15V and 20V in its different versions. Wikipedia doesn't say anything about adjustable voltage. The cheaper adapter entirely lacks 15V.

Because of the adjustable voltage, the 5-18V, 19-20V adapter seems like a better purchase. But, does USB power delivery actually support freely adjustable voltage? Or is the freely adjustable voltage of the more expensive adapter just a marketing trick?

The higher power of the first adapter doesn't matter to me as charging a feeble 7.4V 1040mAh battery doesn't require that much power.

**Edit:**

[A report on the 'net](https://www.dpreview.com/forums/thread/4329226) says:

> Just incase anybody was wondering... I got the official Canon PD-E1 USB-C adapter (it's included with the battery grip) and the output listed on it is 5V/3A and 9V/3A.

...so I guess the 65W adapter should work.

Comment: Do you have the specification of what is required for the power supply. It would be good to check before connecting it to $2000 worth of camera.

Comment: Variable voltages are delivered by the charger asking the device what it wants. It would be trivial for Canon to use proprietary rather than standard protocols to do this if they wanted to lock you into their dedicated charger, so it's possible your standard charger won't work. I have a Dell laptop that refuses to charge unless it's talking to a Dell power supply.

Comment: Did you read: https://dancarrphotography.com/blog/2019/03/11/best-usb-charger-and-battery-for-the-canon-eos-rp-eos-r/ ?

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I do recall reading that, yes. The reports on the 'net that USB power delivery adapters work just fine made me think of not purchasing the expensive Canon adapter.

Comment: 65W 6 port 5V 2.1A hubs are cheap. Why not use this with suitable cable to USB.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 I think the Canon requires 9V / 3A from the adapter; at least Canon's own adapter is 9V / 3A. Furthermore, the Canon requires support for USB power delivery; do the 6-port USB hubs support power delivery?

Comment: Then for only $50 you can choose the 20Ah charger from Anker

Comment: I found a cheap $8 PD 3.0 chargers with US shipping advertised as 45w, but that was probably including heat loss or some funny math. Their specs topped out at 30w. Fine by me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, actually reading the Wikipedia a second time answered my question:

> The USB Power Delivery specification revision 3.0 defines a programmable power supply protocol that allows granular control over VBUS power in 20 mV steps to facilitate constant current or constant voltage charging. Revision 3.0 also adds extended configuration messages, fast role swap, and deprecates the BFSK protocol.

So, apparently the adjustable voltage power supply supports USB power delivery version 3.0 whereas the cheaper power supplies support only older versions of USB power delivery.

I think for future-proofing my purchase, I will select the adjustable voltage power supply. There may be some need for using the PSU with future devices that expect revision 3.0 support.