# Is it possible to get constant 12V from USB PD?

Tags: usb, dc-dc-converter, usb-pd

I am interested in using Power Banks to get a 12V constant power supply. From the USB-C Specification, I get this figure which shows that it is impossible to get 15 V with insufficient sink current.

I assume that the only way is to implement a Buck/Boost 5..20V -> 12V with an MCU that does the PD negotiation. It that correct?

[image]

Comment: It depends on what version of the standard the power bank complied to. See https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/446910/112028

Comment: "it is impossible to get 15 V with insufficient sink current" - do you mean that you have to sink a minimum amount of current to get 15V? I don't think, that's what the diagram says. I'm pretty certain, it shows the maximum current/power you can sink in the individual voltage levels.